# A sequence of continuous functions converging to sgn(F) a.e. on a finite measurable set

Tags: real-analysis

How to construct a sequence of continuous functions converging to sgn(F) a.e. on E, E is an measurable set and its measure is finite.
F is an integrable function on E.

Thank you very much for any helpful ideas.

Comment: What is sgn(F) ?

Comment: Sgn means sign function and F is as what is in the question

Answer (score 1):

Given $n \in \mathbb N$, take disjoint compact sets $A$, $B$, $C$ such that $F < 0$ on $A$, $F = 0$ on $B$ and $F > 0$ on $C$, with $m(E \backslash (A \cup B \cup C)) < 2^{-n}$.  Use Tietze Extension Theorem to find a continuous $F_n$ so $F_n = -1$ on $A$, $0$ on $B$ and $1$ on $C$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
 $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x>1/n\\ nx& -1/n\le x\le 1/n\\ -1& x<-1/n\end{cases}$$ do The work for $F(x)=x$.

Comment: It helps. But if F is not continuous on E and actually we don’t know its concrete function expression, in this case, how could we do?

Comment: Also  valid for Riemann integrable functions